# How to clear cookies before running test using cypress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, cypress

Below is my code to that explains my login flow.

```
  cy.getCookies()      // returns [{cookie1, cookie2}]
  cy.clearCookies()    // clears both cookies
  cy.getCookies()      // again returning [{cookie1, cookie2}]   WHY?
  goToLoginPage();
  fillLoginDetails(email, password);
  login(201);
  verifyHomePage();
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it. If I start the sequence with `cy.setCookie('auth_key', '123key')`, then `cy.clearCookies()` the next `cy.getCookies()` returns an empty array.

Comment: I suspect some misunderstanding of how Cypress works regards to asynchronous execution.

Comment: Please provide an example we can reproduce, what you have given does not show the problem.